# Order of Redactor format options using formattingAdd

Tags: redactor

I'm using formattingAdd in a JSON config file for redactor. The items do not appear in the menu in the order I define them.

After some searching I realise the format for formattingAdd is an object and each format is a property of that object. Javascript does not guarantee the order of properties returned from an object.

The redactor source code uses jQuery $.each which cannot 'fix' the issue with javascript not ordering the properties of an object.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? I could change the code in craft/app/resources/lib/redactor/redactor.js to accept an array of objects for formattingAdd but I guess it would be overwritten everytime I upgrade craft.

Comment: I am curious, using which browser do you experience this?

Comment: Safari on Mac, also tested on Chrome and it behaves in the same way.

Comment: No idea why this was down-voted; I'd love to have a solution to this, too. One of the `formattingAdd` options I'm adding should be _above_ the H1. :-/